# Testing calendar anomalies

Tags: regression, time-series, linear-model

I have time series of returns of some stock $X_1,X_2,...X_t$. I want to test if day of the week has some effect on returns.  I am considering using the following regression (where $D_i$ are five dummy variables for each day of the week):

$$X_t = \sum a_i D_i + \epsilon$$

Is this regression viable for my needs?

Comment: You will only be able to fit four as they are not all independent. However surely your software does this for you?